# Calculate number of days between two dates using 5 day week

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel-2013

What is the formula to determine the number of days between two dates (ie. Disability start date and return to work date) without including the weekends?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [NETWORKDAYS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/networkdays-HP005209190.aspx) function.